# Irish Setter or Cocker Spaniel?

Tags: dogs, identification

I'm currently learning about dog breeds and I would like to know which breed of dog the following is. Is it an Irish Setter or a red English Cocker Spaniel? Thanks.

[image: Irish Setter or Cocker Spaniel?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dog looks like a mix of possibly and English Cocker Spaniel and Irish Setter. The [setter has longer legs](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=irish%20setter&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx0cPM9J7VAhVHwrwKHfPoCPEQ_AUICigB&biw=1455&bih=632), the [English Cocker Spaniel has a shorter stout body](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=english%20cocker%20spaniel&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0p7a89J7VAhVHVrwKHTtrDYcQ_AUICigB&biw=1455&bih=632).

This dog seems to be lacking the sleek, angular body of the setter, but it's legs seem to be too long to be an English Cocker Spaniel. To be honest, it looks like a mixture. More pictures are always helpful, to get a better look.

Answer (score 0):

Given the high ears, the fur and the high legs, I suspect that this is a Cocker Spaniel with more hunting lines. I have a puppy of 7 months with the same characteristics.